# prove two metrics determine the same topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that the euclidean topology $d_E$ and $d(x,y) = \left| \frac{1}{2^x}- \frac{1}{2^y}\right|$ determine the same topology.

My work: I assume you want to show that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and every $\epsilon > 0$, where  $B^{d_E}_{\epsilon}(x)$ is some open ball in the euclidean metric, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that there is some $B_{\delta}^{d}(x) \subseteq B^{d_E}_{\epsilon}(x)$. The problem is I cannot find a relation between $\left| \frac{1}{2^x}- \frac{1}{2^y}\right|$ and $|x-y|$ to use to find $\delta$.

Any help on this would be really appreciated! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to go both ways. I’ll do the other direction as a sort of model.

Draw the graph of $f(x)=\dfrac1{2^x}$. Note that for any $x,y\in\Bbb R$ you have $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$. In other words, the $d$-distance between $x$ and $y$ is the vertical distance between the points $\langle x,f(x)\rangle$ and $\langle y,f(y)\rangle$, and the Euclidean distance is the horizontal distance between those points.

Take the $\epsilon$-ball $B_\epsilon^d(x)$, where $\epsilon<f(x)$. Examining the graph, you should see that

$$\begin{align*}
B_\epsilon^d(x)&=\{y\in\Bbb R:f(x)-\epsilon<f(y)<f(x)+\epsilon\}\\
&=\left(f^{-1}\big(f(x)+\epsilon\big),f^{-1}\big(f(x)-\epsilon\big)\right)\;,
\end{align*}$$

which is an open interval around $x$. If you let

$$\delta=\min\left\{x-f^{-1}\big(f(x)+\epsilon\big),f^{-1}\big(f(x)-\epsilon\big)-x\right\}\;,$$

you’ll have $B_\delta^{d_E}(x)\subseteq B_\epsilon^d(x)$.

Now take $B_\epsilon^{d_E}(x)$; $y\in B_\epsilon^{d_E}(x)$ if and only if $f(y)$ satisfies a certain inequality condition. Use that condition to find a $\delta$ such that $B_\delta^d(x)\subseteq B_\epsilon^{d_E}(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know, that the standard topology on $\bf R$ is determined by all open intervals, the solution is simple: function $1/2^x$ transforms $\bf R$ onto $(0,+\infty)$ and for every $(c,d)$ in $(0,+\infty)$ the ends $c$, $d$ are determined by their logarithms (base $1/2$) in $\bf R$.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, although I'm not sure if I follow  you. Are you just saying that if we have a function $f = \frac{1}{2^x}$, then for any open interval in $(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $(log_{1/2}(a), log_{1/2}(b)$? I'm not sure if I understand where to go from here

Comment: @Rick If you have already topological bases, you can know, that topology on $\bf R$ is determined by open intervals. If not, as $1/2^x$ (or logarithm) is continuous, for a chosen $\epsilon$ you can find proper $\delta$, with or without calculations (probably the first may be expected).

Comment: Okay, I think I understand and I would definitely like to do this without calculations as I have never been very good at epsilon delta stuff. How do I go about finding an open interval for $d$ contained in an open interval for $d_E$ though? This is not actually for an assignment, I am just trying to teach myself topology

Comment: @Rick It is a definition of (metric) continuity: $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ if $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x\ |x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$. And your $x_0$ may be chosen as, e.g. centre of interval.

Comment: I'm really not following, I'm sorry. I understand the metric definition of continuity, but I don't understand how to use that to prove that the two metrics determine the same topology, are you talking about creating a homeomorphism between them?

Comment: @Rick You may create homeomorphism between $(0,\infty)$ and $\bf R$, indeed. Or, even easier than sugested at the beginning of the answer, you can show, that every open interval is some ball in first and second metric (of course, balls parameters are different). The comment just above suggest, how to find epsilon and delta, as in your work in question.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm just not understanding how to find $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ to show that the balls are contained within one-another.